# create a new var whose value should be the square difference between the two other variables in r

Tags: r

Create a new variable whose values should be a square of the difference between imdbrating and imdbvotes

```
imdbRating = (as.numeric (IMDB_data$imdbRating))
imdbVotes =(as.numeric (IMDB_data$imdbVotes))
IMDB_data$z = with(IMDB_data, (imdbRating-imdbVotes)^2)'
```

Warning message:

> In Ops.factor(imdbRating, imdbVotes) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

even after converting the variables from factor to numeric I got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encounter that error since you did not used the variables `imdbRating` and `imdbVotes` (you are still using `IMDB_data$imdbRating` and `IMDB_data$imdbVotes`, which are factors).

To address, you should do it like below

```
imdbRating = (as.numeric (IMDB_data$imdbRating))
imdbVotes =(as.numeric (IMDB_data$imdbVotes))
IMDB_data$z = (imdbRating-imdbVotes)^2
```

or just the one-line command

```
IMDB_data = within(IMDB_data, z <- (as.numeric(imdbRating)-as.numeric(imdbVotes))^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You made 2 new variables which are not in the data frame `IMDB_data`. Try:

```
IMDB_data$imdbRating <- as.numeric (IMDB_data$imdbRating)
IMDB_data$imdbVotes <- as.numeric (IMDB_data$imdbVotes)
IMDB_data$z <- with(IMDB_data, (imdbRating - imdbVotes)^2)
```

Comment: thank you . rectified it and got the output .   one more doubt , if its in a categorical form & i have to get in numeric form do i have to convert it into factor first and then into numeric ?? or directly?

Comment: No, you don't need to convert it first to factor.